# Revolving the earth around Sun in Unity 3D version 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a scene in unity 3D. It has 3 spheres, one is the sun, second the earth and third the moon.  I have made Moon the child of Earth. My Earth revolves vertically around the sun and moon revolves around the earth. I want the revolution on a horizontal axis.

The code for revolution is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class revolve : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;    // the object to rotate around

public int speed;   // the speed of rotation

void Start()
 {
if (target == null) 
{
target = this.gameObject.transform;
Debug.Log ("RotateAround target not specified. Defaulting to parent GameObject");
}}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
// RotateAround takes three arguments, first is the Vector to rotate around
// second is a vector that axis to rotate around
// third is the degrees to rotate, in this case the speed per second
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,target.transform.forward,speed * Time.deltaTime);
}}
```

Suggest what changes to be done to revolve on horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0):

Change this last line

```
 transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,target.transform.forward,speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

to

```
 transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,target.transform.right,speed * Time.deltaTime);
```